# I am going through infinite loop when adding values to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created an array with some movie names by default. I have an form which asks for user input, if the user input matches with my default array it should pop up that movie already exists, if user input is different from my default array it should store in different array. I have done the first part but I'm getting issues with adding values to array

```js
function insert() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
  var movie2 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= movie2.length; i++) {

    if (movie !== movie2[i]) {
      movie2.push(movie);
      var name2 = "Movie added into Array2";
      alert(name2);
    } else {
      var name2 = "Movie already added to Array2";
      alert(name2);
    }
  }
}

function validation() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
  var movie1 = ["Bahubali", "The Final Destination", "The Cars", "P.K", "Bajarangi Baijaan", "Force"];

  if (movie == "") {
    var name2 = "Please enter your favoite movie name";
    alert(name2);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < movie1.length; i++) {

    if (movie == movie1[i]) {
      var name2 = "Movie exists in our database";
      alert(name2);

    } else {
      insert();

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Movie Mania</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Movie.css">
  <script src="Movie.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content">

    <div class="matter">

      <p class="header">Movie Mania</p>
      <div class="regis">

        <form class="reg">

          <input type="text" name="user" id="movie" placeholder="Please enter 
            any movie name" size="40">
          <hr>
          <div><input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" id="sub" onclick="validation()" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your  movie2.length is 0!! (for i = 0 to 0 step 1) ?

Comment: The downvote is not correct. The for loop checks movie.length. Everytime when  pushing an Element  length is length +1 and the loop is an never ending story.

Answer (score 0):

It's for loop problem .

> **Explanation of for loop problem**
>
> See the `console.log` matching the condition for each arguments of
>   array. you are not breaking after the true statement. so only else
>   statement also run(*`insert`*) until for loop finishing

```js
var one = "hi"
var arr = ['hello', 'hi', 'how']

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i] == one)
  if (arr[i] == one) {
    break;
  }
}
```

**Solution:*you should use [`break`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_break.asp) statement*** .

See the console.log the loop was stopped the execution after break

```js
var one="hi"
var arr = ['hello','hi','how']

for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
console.log(arr[i] == one) 
}
```

For better use with [`Array#includes`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl-OnDh4vUAhUHwI8KHfTHBTEQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fincludes&usg=AFQjCNH5UxAefwkcnRMTtq3VoGcYGJuHDg) instead of for loop iteration

**Updated:**

remove the `movie2` `.push(movie)` with `movie1` and declare the `movie1` array as a global

```js
var movie1 = ["Bahubali", "The Final Destination", "The Cars ","P.K ","   Bajarangi Baijaan ","Force "];

function insert() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
    if (!movie1.includes(movie)) { //  ! refer for false statement 
      movie1.push(movie);
      var name2 = "Movie added into Array2";
      console.log(name2);
    } else {
      var name2 = "Movie already added to Array2";
      cosole.log(name2);
    }
    console.log(movie1)
  }

function validation() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
    if (!movie.trim()) { //its validate the input empty undefined null
      var name2 = "Please enter your favoite movie name";
      console.log(name2);
    }
    else if (movie1.includes(movie)) { // includes used for  find the value is in array or not
        var name2 = "Movie exists in our database";
        console.log(name2);
      } else {
        insert();
      }
      return false;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="matter">

    <p class="header">Movie Mania</p>
    <div class="regis">

      <form class="reg">

        <input type="text" name="user" id="movie" placeholder="Please enter 
        any movie name" size="40">
        <hr>
        <div><input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" id="sub" onclick="return validation()" /></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code!!!  If the user enters the movie name it is getting added to array 2 but when im giving same name again it should compare with values in array2 and if it matches it should say that movie already added to array2

Comment: @PraneethKumar simply remove the `movie2` .push with `movie1` and declare the `movie1` array as a global see my updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

the cause of the infinite loop is:

```
var movie2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= movie2.length; i++) {
    if (movie !== movie2[i]) {
      movie2.push(movie);
      var name2 = "Movie added into Array2";
      alert(name2);
    } else {
      var name2 = "Movie already added to Array2";
      alert(name2);
    }
  }
```

you start with `i = 0` and since the array is empty this will be true `i <= movie2.length` since the array is empty `movie2[i] == undefined` so you push the movie to the array, next iteration `i` will be `1` and `movie2.length` will be `1` too but `movie2[1]` is `undefined` so you push the movie again, and that will keep repeating.

One way to solve this is to check if the movie exist or not then push it:

*this code still have some other issues unrelated to the question*

```js
function insert() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
  var movie2 = [];
  var found = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < movie2.length; i++) {
    if (movie !== movie2[i]) {
      found = true
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (!found) {
    movie2.push(movie);
    var name2 = "Movie added into Array2";
    alert(name2);
  } else {
    var name2 = "Movie already added to Array2";
    alert(name2);
  }
}

function validation() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
  var movie1 = ["Bahubali", "The Final Destination", "The Cars", "P.K", "Bajarangi Baijaan", "Force"];

  if (movie == "") {
    var name2 = "Please enter your favoite movie name";
    alert(name2);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < movie1.length; i++) {
    if (movie == movie1[i]) {
      var name2 = "Movie exists in our database";
      alert(name2);
    } else {
      insert();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Movie Mania</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Movie.css">
  <script src="Movie.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content">

    <div class="matter">

      <p class="header">Movie Mania</p>
      <div class="regis">

        <form class="reg">

          <input type="text" name="user" id="movie" placeholder="Please enter 
            any movie name" size="40">
          <hr>
          <div><input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" id="sub" onclick="validation()" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

a slightly improved version

```js
var movie1 = ["Bahubali", "The Final Destination", "The Cars", "P.K", "Bajarangi Baijaan", "Force"];
var movie2 = [];


function insert() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < movie2.length; i++) {
    if (movie !== movie2[i]) {
      found = true
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    movie2.push(movie);
    var name2 = "Movie added into Array2";
    alert(name2);
  } else {
    var name2 = "Movie already added to Array2";
    alert(name2);
  }
}

function validation() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;

  if (movie == "") {
    var name2 = "Please enter your favoite movie name";
    alert(name2);
  }
  
  var found = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < movie1.length; i++) {
    if (movie == movie1[i]) {
      found = true
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (found) {
    var name2 = "Movie exists in our database";
    alert(name2);
  } else {
    insert();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Movie Mania</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Movie.css">
  <script src="Movie.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content">

    <div class="matter">

      <p class="header">Movie Mania</p>
      <div class="regis">

        <form class="reg">

          <input type="text" name="user" id="movie" placeholder="Please enter 
            any movie name" size="40">
          <hr>
          <div><input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" id="sub" onclick="validation()" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem that you are facing is in your loop logic. You are visiting every element of the array and checking if that element is equal to the new value. If it is not then you are inserting the value.

Say your array contained:

```
 ["A", "B"]
```

And you wish to insert "C".

First, you code is comparing "A" to "C" and since they are not equal you are inserting "C" so the array becomes

```
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Then your for loop moves on to compare "B" and "C" and since they are not equal you are inserting "C" again.

To make matters worse your insert method is also doing a similar task by looping through the array again and actually inserting the new value for every movie that is already in your array.

So to solve the problem your logic should be:

1. Check if the movie exist in the array
2. If not insert it
3. If it does provide a message.

To check if the movie already exist in the array you may use the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control) method of arrays. Something like this:

```
   if (movie1.includes(movie)){
      //movie is already in array
   }else{
      //movie is not yet in array
   }
```